# How to make a key act as acute and apostrophe? dead keys problem

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, languages, external-keyboard, cyanogenmod

Hi dear android/linux enthusiast, first question on stackoverflow, until now I've got a lot of help just reading stackexchange.* in passive mode, thanks for all that!

I want to make a keycharmap/keylayout for my bluetooth keyboard in my android phone. I want it to behave like a dvorack-us-international keyboard. So I made all the web-research needed but I'm still missing one thing. In my PC the apostrophe key behaves as an acute key, if I press it once and then press a vowel, it writes the vowel with the acute (my native language is Spanish so I've become dependent on this "feature"), so I want this behavior in android.

In my PC:

```
APOSTROPHE A = á
APOSTROPHE O = ó
APOSTROPHE Shift+A = Á
APOSTROPHE APOSTROPHE = ´ (lonely acute)
APOSTROPHE SPACE = '
Shift+APOSTROPHE A = ä
Shift+APOSTROPHE Shift+A = Ä
Shift+APOSTROPHE Shift+APOSTROPHE = ¨ (umlaut)
Shift+APOSTROPHE SPACE = "
```

So I made a keycharmap that has this:

```
key APOSTROPHE {
    label:                              '\''
    base:                               '\u0301'
    shift:                              '\u0308'
}
```

(As sepecified in https://source.android.com/devices/tech/input/key-character-map-files.html#behaviors)

But what I've got was this behavior:

```
APOSTROPHE APOSTROPHE = ´ (lonely acute)
APOSTROPHE SPACE = ´ (lonely acute)
Shift+APOSTROPHE Shift+APOSTROPHE = ¨ (umlaut)
Shift+APOSTROPHE SPACE = ¨ (umlaut)
```

As you can see **I'm missing the quote and double quote** and I'd really like to have them.

So, I tried something different:

```
key APOSTROPHE {
    label:                              '\''
    base:                               '\u030D'
    shift:                              '\u030E'
}
```

(Looking at android sources http://omapzoom.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/view/KeyCharacterMap.java;h=55dd6bb64fe65ba29c5f71ed9257ed9dbe7a3790;hb=HEAD and at unicode "combining character" in wikipedia)

But didn't got what I wanted either. I saw that the character '\u030E' was comment-out on the source code ok, but I had to try. So the question is:

How do I get the behavior I want in android? Can't be done without modifying android sources? do I have to use key modifiers (ALT or CTRL) and stick with that?

(I'm using cyanogenmod 11-20140708 based on kitkat 4.4.4 on a LG nexus 4 (mako))

thanks!

Comment: But this is not a question related to developing or publishing aplications, this is a question about how to use a different bluetooth keyboard layout. It has a little hack but it's still from the point of view of a user. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is not the answer, this is some kind of "workaround" that I don't like. It works but makes me memorize another super key combo.

```
# In the keycharmap I puted this:

# this is the default for this key
key GRAVE {
    label:                              '`'
    base:                               '`'
    shift:                              '~'
    alt:                                '\u0300'
    alt+shift:                          '\u0303'
}

key APOSTROPHE {
    label:                              '\''
    base:                               '\''
    shift:                              '"'
    alt:                                '\u0301'
    alt+shift:                          '\u0308'
}
```

And with that settings I get this results:

```
Alt+APOSTROPHE A = á
Alt+APOSTROPHE O = ó
Alt+APOSTROPHE Shift+A = Á
Alt+APOSTROPHE Alt+APOSTROPHE = ´ (lonely acute)
APOSTROPHE = '
Alt+Shift+APOSTROPHE A = ä
Alt+Shift+APOSTROPHE Shift+A = Ä
Alt+Shift+APOSTROPHE Alt+Shift+APOSTROPHE = ¨ (umlaut)
Shift+APOSTROPHE = "
```

Using Alt+Shift feels unnatural and I'd like to get the same behavior that I've got on my PC, but for now this works.